# A word for a 'wild stream'?

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a word describing water flowing fast and aggressively like white water. Is there a single word describing that kind of flow?

The main thing it should convey is the fast and wild flow of the water.

Comment: *Turbulent*, perhaps?

Comment: FYI, turbidity (turbulence) is the status of suspended particles as a result of the fluid.  With me, anyway, it describes haphazard and erratic movements and restlessness.  If the water is simply moving rapidly, then I do not think it would work as well.

Comment: Look up the distinction between turbulent and laminar flow. White water is turbulent.  laminar flow is smooth, but is usually present only in short stretches before rocks or other irregularities in the stream break the smooth flow.  Turbulent flow is an example of chaos.

Comment: @can-ned_food while they are etymologically related in Latin, *turbulent* and *turbid* don't mean the same thing.  Turbulence can stir up particles leading to turbidity downstream

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Torrent**
[Oxford Online Dictionary defines as](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/torrent):

> **: A strong and fast-moving stream of water or other liquid.** 
> *‘rain poured
>   down in torrents’
> ‘after the rains, **the stream becomes a raging***
>   torrent’

Also consider **Rapid**  [Also Oxford Online](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/rapid)

> (usually *rapids*) 
> **A fast-flowing and turbulent part of the course of a
>   river.** 
> ‘*those of you looking for adventure can shoot the rapids*’

Answer (score 3):

I think a sports person would call it a ***white-water stream/river***.

That follows the name of the sports which take place on such watercourses, such as ***white-water rafting/canoeing*** etc.

Answer (score 1):

I think "rushing river" is an apt and common phrase.

https://www.google.com/search?q=rushing+river&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjI1ouh-6bUAhVkxYMKHQ2TDkwQ_AUICigB&biw=1680&bih=906